# Remove specific punctuation from the list elements in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

From a song lyrics, I have to fetch every word as elements without including any commas (,) in element.
For example:

> She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah
>   She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah, yeah
>   You think you lost your love
>   Well, I saw her yesterday
>   It's you she's thinking of
>   And she told me what to say
>   She says she loves you
>   And you know that can't be bad

I do split the lyrics into list elements and then made them into lower case letters. Then I tried to find commas from the list and separated them. Now I want to remove commas (,) from the list elements.

Here is my code:

```
text_file = open("Beatles.txt", "r")
lines= text_file.read().split()
x.lower() for x in ["A","B","C"]]
re.findall(r"[\w]+|[.,!?;]", "Hello, I'm a string!")
```

My output is:

> ['she',
>    'loves',
>    ',',
>    'you',
>    ',',
>    ',',
>    ',',
>    ',',
>    'yeah',
>    ',',
>    ',',
>    'yeah',
>    ',',
>    'she',
>    ',',
>    'loves',
>    ',',
>    'you',
>    ',',
>    ',',
>    'yeah',
>    ',',
>    ',',
>    'yea']

My expected output is:

> ['she',
>    'loves',
>    'you',
>    'yeah',
>    'yeah',
>    'she',
>    'loves',
>    'you',
>    'yeah',
>    'yea']

Comment: How did you get your desired output. Why aren't words like `thinking` in it?

Comment: The code represented here is a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex to remove commas and lower case:

```
s = "She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah, yeah You think you lost your love Well, I saw her yesterday It's you she's thinking of And she told me what to say She says she loves you And you know that can't be bad"
s = ''.join(c.lower() for c in s if c != ',')
print(s.split())
```

Output:

```
['she', 'loves', 'you', 'yeah', 'yeah', 'yeah', 'she', 'loves', 'you', 'yeah', 'yeah', 'yeah', 'yeah', 'you', 'think', 'you', 'lost', 'your', 'love', 'well', 'i', 'saw', 'her', 'yesterday', "it's", 'you', "she's", 'thinking', 'of', 'and', 'she', 'told', 'me', 'what', 'to', 'say', 'she', 'says', 'she', 'loves', 'you', 'and', 'you', 'know', 'that', "can't", 'be', 'bad']
```

Comment: I do need some specific outputs like "it's", "can't" etc. I just want to remove the commas (,).

Comment: Thank you a lot :)